# JVM: Can't detect initial thread stack location - find_vma failed

Tags: java, jvm

```
The compilation was successful
The multiplication should have been performed at compile time without any code being generated.
However, your solution generated the following code:
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Can't detect initial thread stack location - find_vma failed
        mov  ax,5
        mov  ax,6
        mul  ax
    [ the expected value was 30, but you calculated the result as 6 ]
```

I entered some code in my school's system and I got this error message. I don't understand the part where it says "The multiplication should have been performed at compile time without any code being generated.".

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

(I can't reveal the code I entered in it, because I don't want it showing up in a search engine. Is there a way I can privately show the code I entered in?)

Comment: Is your class about writing a compiler? If not, what are you expected to do for the assignment?

Comment: You could post the code to a web server and include a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) that asks search engines to not index it. Not all search engines will respect the robots.txt obviously, but the big ones do.

Comment: That looks a lot like the assembly you would generate if incorrectly converting stack-based code (JVM) to register-based (x86, MIPS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Can't detect initial thread stack location` suggests an incomplete or corrupt Java installation.

The stuff about multiplication at compile time doesn't look like it comes from Java, but instead from some sort of IDE or compilation tool that your school is using. Whatever this "school system" is, you need to ask whoever is responsible for it about these error messages.

Comment: Okay, you're probably right. Because it compiles and runs properly on BlueJ, but when I enter it to the system I get an error message. I currently on holiday, so I have to wait till I resume Uni to contact my tutor (there's no email on course site).

Answer (score 15):

On my Ubuntu 10.04/64-bit system, `java` was unable to access the `/proc` filesystem.
Specifically, I was running in a `chroot` which didn't have it mounted:

`mount -t proc none /proc`

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem in my `chroot` environment.  As @chronospoon suggested, it is because java was unable to access the /proc filesystem.

However, the correct mounting command is the following (note that both proc does not prefixed by `/`), as mentioned in [here](http://www.funtoo.org/Funtoo_Linux_Installation):

```
mount -t proc none proc
```

To check whether the mounting is successful, just check whether the `proc` directory has any file.

Comment: Ah, this is for mounting the /proc filesystem _before_ calling chroot, mine is for mounting it _inside_ the chroot.

Answer (score 1):

The message "Can't detect initial thread stack location" is quite common, see e.g., [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/tomcat-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg155591.html) [and here](http://www.open-java.info/1/3/115778.html). The remaining part is strange, the assembly code is pure nonsense. I wouldn't care about that, it isn't your fault.

Comment: It's been awhile since I programmed assembly, but I also thought that moving two different values to the same register and executing a multiple instruction on that register was unlikely to be valid.  However, it's probably right about the result being 6 since AX is probably multiplied by a different register which happens to have a 1 in it.

Comment: No, AFAIK, `mul ax` means `ax = ax*ax`, so the the three instructions could be replaced by `mov ax, 36`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is an artifact of the "school system" that you are using, which appears to be some framework for automating code testing.

- The message looks system specific to me.
- If the message is no system specific, it is a (arguably) a bug for a production application to be reporting obscure HotSpot errors to end users.

So, I think you should be asking the people who manage the system, and (presumably) understand what that message means.

Comment: Okay, you're probably right. Because it compiles and runs properly on BlueJ, but when I enter it to the system I get an error message. I currently on holiday, so I have to wait till I resume Uni to contact my tutor (there's no email on course site).